# vb.net filter dataview without a bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2022, dataview

I have a dataview that i wnat to filter as you type.
i don't have a bindingsource because honestly i don't know how... :/

if have to use a binding source could you point me to agood tutorial?

my code works for what i need but i want them to be able to search the combobox.

my code:

```
    Private Sub ProspectosMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Fill Prospectos
        Dim dt_Prospectos As DataTable

        dt_Prospectos = Fill("SP_Obtiene_Prospectos", 0)

        Dim dv As DataView = dt_Prospectos.AsDataView()
        dv.Sort = "Compañia"
        dgvProspectosMain.DataSource = dv
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("IdPros").Visible = False
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Compañia").HeaderText = "Compañia"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Contacto").HeaderText = "Contacto"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Dir").HeaderText = "Direccion"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Mail").HeaderText = "Mail"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Telefono").HeaderText = "Telefono 1"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Telefono2").HeaderText = "Telefono 2"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Observaciones").HeaderText = "Observaciones"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("Nombre").HeaderText = "Contacto usalentes"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("FechaAlta").HeaderText = "Fecha de Alta"
        dgvProspectosMain.Columns("IdLocalPuesto").Visible = False

        'Combo Compañias
        Dim dt_Co As DataTable
        dt_Co = Fill("SP_Obtiene_Prospectos_Combos", 0)
        cboCompañia.DataSource = dt_Co
        cboCompañia.DisplayMember = "Compañia"
        cboCompañia.ValueMember = "Compañia"
        'Combo Contactos
        Dim dt_Con As DataTable
        dt_Con = Fill("SP_Obtiene_Prospectos_Combos", 1)
        cboContacto.DataSource = dt_Con
        cboContacto.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
        cboContacto.ValueMember = "Nombre"
    End Sub
```

```
    Public Function Fill(itxt As String, itipo As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Using myConn = New SqlConnection(CadenaConexion)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            cmd.CommandText = itxt
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tipo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = itipo

            myConn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = myConn
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            sda.Fill(dt)
            myConn.Close()

            Fill = dt

        End Using
    End Function
```

what i need is to filter on textchanged

```
    Private Sub cboCompañia_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCompañia.TextChanged

'here i need to filter

    End Sub
```

any help would be apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using the `Filter` of a BindingSource or the DataTable's `RowFiler` is the same thing. It's no different than specifying a `WHERE` clause in SQL. A BindingSource gives you more options in relation to the bindings. You just set the DataSource of a BindingSource to your DataTable, then use the BindingSource as the source of data of any Control. The BindingSource coordinates all bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to the `DataView`...

```
Dim dtb As New DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
dtb.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
dtb.Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
dtb.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C")
dtb.Rows.Add("C", "A", "B")
dtb.Rows.Add("B", "C", "A")

Dim dvw As DataView = New DataView(dtb)
dvw.Sort = "Col3"
dvw.RowFilter = "Col3<'C'"
DataGridView1.DataSource = dvw
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, just one question... how does the "Col3<'C'" work as search as you type? do i put this on the text_changed in the combo? or do i use it like in sql "Compañia like cboCompañia.SelectedValue" or something like that?

Comment: I _think_ you should be able to set the `RowFilter` value in `TextChanged` (or `KeyUp`) event and have the grid update as you type. You will probably need to put in some code to make sure the method doesn't fail if the user types an apostrophe. `Replace(cboCompañia.SelectedValue, '''', '''''')` or similar

Comment: Apologies I completely misread your question, I thought you were using `DataGridView` but you are using `ComboBox`. Searching should be built-in. Just type a few letters then press the down arrow